# Nginx - Can I convert/redirect all root requests for *any domain* to www requests

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx, subdomain

I have a situation where domains' A records will be pointing to my server without my knowledge (ie, I won't be configuring each one manually), but I want all root requests (e.g. `example.com`) to be converted or redirected to their `www` counterpart (e.g. `www.example.com`). Without having to use the text `example.com` in my configuration (because I won't be editing the configuration for each new domain), is this possible to achieve?

Comment: How are you going to setup a new domain in the first place? You need to add a server block to handle requests for each domain.

Comment: @Dayo - Users will point their `www` CNAME to `websites.myappsdomain.com`, and they'll point an A record to an I.P. provided by the app (which is always the same). Nginx will rewrite the domain to always include the `www`, and when the request comes through on the `websites` server that I configure, my app will take their hostname and lookup their site info with that. Will that not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this

```
server {
  server_name    ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;
  root           /sites/$domain/www;
}
```